# Is there a way to distinguish mice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouse, google-earth

I am wanting to hook up several mice - each one used for different types of input.  Is there a way in JavaScript to distinguish between each mouse?

I know that JS may not seem like the right language for this, but I want to use one mouse for web navigation, and the other for Google-earth navigation.  Because the Google-API is already using JS, I figured I try to keep all the code together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with JavaScript. The JS would have to have low-level access to the clients machine to make this type of distinction. Obviously, this would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Alternatively, the distinction could be handled by the browser and offered to JS within the event object. This would be much cleaner and less prone to security problems. That said, as you mentioned, it's not possible right now.

Comment: I figured it was a shot in the dark.  I'll have to write a "driver" of sorts in a native app - but I was hoping to avoid that. - Thanks!

Comment: If you wanna keep it in the JS family you should look at writing something in Node. I know a couple people who've written drivers for game pads in Node.